# Emitting unnamed compat plugin

Tags: laravel, vue.js, node-modules, laravel-mix

I recently deployed my application to my server. I downloaded the deployed project from the server and set it up locally. I'm trying to build the frontend (Vue.js) with `npm run dev`, and It's giving me the following error.

> 95% emitting unnamed compat plugin.

I tried resetting my webpack.mix.js and it didn't help.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', '../public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', '../public/css')
   .styles([
    'resources/vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css',
    'resources/vendor/select2/select2.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/slick/slick.css',
    'resources/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/wow/animate.css',
    'resources/vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/font-face.css',
    'resources/vendor/theme.css'
], '../public/css/all.css');
```

When I run `npm run dev` this error occurs.

```
 npm run watch

> @ watch E:\xampp\htdocs\web\v1
> npm run development -- --watch


> @ development E:\xampp\htdocs\web\v1
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

 10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
webpack is watching the files…

 95% emitting unnamed compat plugin
```

Comment: Please provide your `package.json` file for better understating of project's dependencies.

Comment: I also had this problem, while using an array inside extract() function, but if removing the array, the error disappeared. However, this problem seems to have been fixed now, I upgraded from laravel-mix 4.0.0 to 4.0.16 and now I can put stuff in extract.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate files outside `public` folder, you have to use `mix.setPublicPath(...)` and then modify your assets output path.

Something like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('../public');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js/')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css/')
   .styles([
    'resources/vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css',
    'resources/vendor/select2/select2.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/slick/slick.css',
    'resources/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/wow/animate.css',
    'resources/vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.css',
    'resources/vendor/font-face.css',
    'resources/vendor/theme.css'
], 'css/all.css');
```

Hope it helps.